# PHP - Final input-validate

Tags: php, security, validation, sanitize

i am validating three types of input(string,email,url):

string-validating:

```
    if ($_POST['string'] != "") {
        $string = filter_var($_POST['string'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($string != "") {
            // valid
        } else {
            // not valid
        }
    } else {
        // empty
    }
```

email-validating:

```
    if ($_POST['email'] != "") {
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // valid
        } else {
            // not valid
    } else {
        // empty
    }
```

url-validating:

```
    if ($_POST['url'] != "") {
        $url = filter_var($_POST['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            // valid
        } else {
            // not valid
        }
    } else {
        // empty
    }
```

After doing this checks i use PDO - Prepared statements to inserate in database.

You think this is secure enough or did i missed some points?

Hope for your answers, thanks and greetings!

Comment: so no more issue´s to add?